# How choose UTF-8 enconding for Cirillic to save logs Java Wrapper tanuki?

Tags: java, wrapper, java-service-wrapper, tanuki

I installed service by Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 3.5.32-st in Windows 2012 R2.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | [00:57:53 05.05.2017]: Um_Scheduler 2.1.0.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | [00:57:53 05.05.2017]: ?????? ???????? ????????. ???????? ? ?? Oracle.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | C:\Server\Tomcat\webapps\um\resources\config\oracle_connection.cfg
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:53 | [00:57:53 05.05.2017]: ??????? ??????? Update. 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:55 | [00:57:53 05.05.2017]: Update ????????
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:55 | [00:57:55 05.05.2017]: ??????? ??????? 3; ???? - ????; ????????? ?????? ??? 00:52 05.05.2017
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:57:55 | [00:57:55 05.05.2017]: ??????????? update ?????????? ???????: 3 ????? ??????? ????????????? ?? 01:00 05.05.2017. Update ????????
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:58:05 | [00:58:05 05.05.2017]: ??????? ??????? 3; ???? - ?????; ?????? ???????????? ?? 01:00 05.05.2017
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:58:15 | [00:58:15 05.05.2017]: ??????? ??????? 3; ???? - ?????; ?????? ???????????? ?? 01:00 05.05.2017
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/05/05 00:58:25 | [00:58:25 05.05.2017]: ??????? ??????? 3; ???? - ?????; ?????? ???????????? ?? 01:00 05.05.2017
```

How choose UTF-8 enconding for Cirillic to save logs Java Wrapper tanuki?

I already tried uncommenting the line

```
#encoding=UTF-8
```

and adding

```
wrapper.app.env.LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

However, result not good.